# how to do a real time CNN classification prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, sentiment-analysis

I had made a sentiment analysis  model on some imdb reviews and getting scores of 86% accuracy. Is there any way to do a real time prediction on some text and the model classifies that into positive / negative?

I had tried the following but seem to be getting weird scores( im thinking closer to 0 is negative and towards 1 is positive?)
Would like a way to demonstrate the model in real time.

Thanks.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
nltk.download('punkt')
word2index = imdb.get_word_index()
test=[]
for word in word_tokenize( "i am bad"):
     test.append(word2index[word])

test=sequence.pad_sequences([test],maxlen=max_review_length)
model.predict(test)
```

```
Out [18] : array([[0.4193488]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What does it mean in real-time here?

Comment: like inputting a phrase such as "i am bad" and the model outputs a result whether it is a positive or negative sentiment.

Comment: Then you need a while loop to get input(s) from the user.

Comment: Use a pipeline in which the first part will be a Scraper function which will scrape all the reviews in an Excel / Json. Then the reviews stored will be fed to the ML model as the input and the classes Positive or Negative will be  the output column. Time it by running automatically once in a day or week so that you can get the latest data and model it accordingly. The results can then be visualised with any of Pivot Chart/ tableau/powerBI/ any other visualization with the model being deployed.